# Why is my icon not shaped like other icons on Android?

Tags: android, flutter, android-icons

I'm using [Launching Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.05&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(255%2C%20255%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=launcher_icon) to build my Android Icon Apps, but I can't get the same shape to the other icons in Android. **What's wrong?**

My icon in the mobile screen looks like that...

[image: My icon doesn't have the same shape]

I'm using Lainching Icon Generator in this way...

[image: Configuring my Icon in Launcher]

How to be sure that my Icon will adapt the Icon Shapes in different Android versions?

Comment: have you tried the circle instead of the square shape

Comment: Yes. If I do that, the icon appears circular. I would like it to take the shape according to the Android version on each mobile.

Answer (score 2):

for better solution u can use android studio in build tab "Image Asset".
from there u can select foreground as your icon and background as your background theme.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @amimic11. I don't use Android Studio. I use VS Code :( Do you know an online tool to fix it?

Comment: well in that case u can use the "inkscape" to add the rounded background, its easy to use as well.
https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0.1/

Comment: To start Image Asset Studio, follow these steps: In the Project window, select the Android view. Right-click the res folder and select New > Image Asset

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding which is set to 25 in attached screenshot. Also make sure to have transparent background.

Comment: The background color cannot be set to transparent. I tried with 0 padding and white background, but it doesn't work. How can I set transparent Background in Launcher Icon Generator?